# Cannot access Textview inside fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments, textview

I have an activity with a fragment on it that has a TextView inside. In the CourseFragment.java I made a simple method that changes the text of the TextView. However, when I try to call the fragment's method from the Activity, it says that the TextView object is null. Here is some of my code:

**CourseFragment.java**

```
public class CourseFragment extends Fragment {

private Subject subject;
View rootView;
private TextView title;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_course, container,
            false);

    title = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.course_title);

    return rootView;
}

public void setTitle() {
    title.setText("My Title");
}

}
```

this is the code in my activity that makes the new fragment and puts in the right location:

```
CourseFragment fragment = new CourseFragment();
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.course1, fragment);
fragment.setTitle();
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.commit();
```

the error coming from the setTitle() method inside the fragment

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
```

this seems so straight forward yet I don't understand why I keep getting NPE. I looked at similar questions about this and tried all the accepted solutions but to no avail. any ideas?

thanks in advance

edit: here is some more code as per requested:

the beginning of **fragment_course.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/course_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.stagenda.stagenda.CourseFragment"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        tools:ignore="UselessParent"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/course_container">
<TextView
        android:text="Course Given Title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/course_given_title"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
    android:text="Course Title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/course_title"
    android:layout_below="@+id/course_given_title"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_light" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Course Code"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/course_code"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/course_title"
        android:layout_below="@+id/course_given_title"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp" />
```

full error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.stagenda.stagenda, PID: 1654
                  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5639)
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22387)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6088)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5639) 
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22387) 
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6088) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776) 
                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                      at com.stagenda.stagenda.CourseFragment.setTitle(CourseFragment.java:34)
                      at com.stagenda.stagenda.MainPage.confirmAddCourse(MainPage.java:435)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5639) 
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22387) 
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6088) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776) 
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 1654 SIG: 9
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8612', transport: 'socket'
```

[explanation of layout (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IxjCT.png)

Comment: Try to set the title after commit method.

Comment: it's better to pass the text in putExtra . So this fragment is not bound .

Comment: no difference if I set the title after commit. thanks for quick reply

Comment: You can pass title in `fragment.setArgumanet(bundle)` and get title on `onCreateView` .

Comment: Why is the activity calling a method on the fragment? This seems like a poor design.

Comment: the text is not the problem. the TextView is null

Comment: show your activity also.

Comment: Please post the stacktrace and tell us which line causes the error. Also post `fragment_course.xml` layout file.

Comment: i posted part of the xml file as well as full error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out myself. The problem was here:

```
CourseFragment fragment = new CourseFragment();
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.course1, fragment);
fragment.setTitle();
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.commit();
```

The problem was that I was calling setTitle() on fragment which did not have its view created. when instead I did the following the problem was solved:

```
CourseFragment fragment = new CourseFragment();
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.course1, fragment);
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.commit();

CourseFragment frag = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.course1);
frag.setTitle();
```

I eventually changed a lot of my code but I hope this helps someone.  thanks for the answers everyone

Answer (score 2):

Go with this approch.

```
 Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("title", "whatever you want to pass");

        CourseFragment fragment = new CourseFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.course1, fragment);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();



    public class CourseFragment extends Fragment {

    private Subject subject;
    View rootView;
    private TextView title;
    Bundle bundle;

      @Override
        public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            bundle = getArguments();
         }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_course, container,
                false);

        title = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.course_title);

        String text = bundle.getString("title");
        title.setText(text);

        return rootView;
    }


    }
```

Comment: @krz if this is not working then check your xml file `course_title` id is there or not.

Comment: i added part of the xml file. the course_title is there

Comment: on the main activity there is a fragment called CoursesFragment(List of courses). Inside CoursesFragment there is another fragment with id course1(first course). CourseFragment gets put into course1.

Comment: here are two screenshots for clarity: https://snag.gy/SJnyFv.jpg https://snag.gy/1JdfOV.jpg

Comment: this approach makes sense for passing arguments between the activity and the fragment but I still get NPE on line: title.setText(text);

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is pass your data as parameters:

```
CourseFragment fragment = new CourseFragment(Your title);
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.course1, fragment);
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.commit();
```

You can also use **Bundle** to pass your data.

Comment: the problem is not passing the data. the problem is telling the fragment to update its TextView

Comment: @krz. pass the data and at `onCreateView` update the title of your fragment. (if you are passing data dynamically from fragment to fragment or from activity to fragment consider listeners(interface).

Answer (score 0):

Fragment transactions are not synchronous. When you add a transaction it can be executed when the main looper has a chance to run it (it gets queued for later).

This means  that the fragment gets attached until after the current method ends. Check the order in which `CourseFragment.setTitle()` and `onCreateView()` are executed.

See docs for FragmentTransaction.commit(): [commit](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#commit())

Consider using `commitNow()` if it works for you.

Also, consider passing the title as an argument to the fragment so that it can be read inside `onCreateView` using `getArguments()`.

Comment: I figured the fragment would have a method for every control that is accessible from the activity. From my research into how android fragments work, I understood that this is the correct way to change controls inside a fragment. Did I misunderstand?

Comment: Consider what happens when the device is rotated and the activity and fragment are both recreated. Will the call to `CourseFragment.setTitle()` run again? I can't tell from the sample code you posted. The ideal is that it doesn't need to. The fragment should have the info to know what text to show in the TextView. This is done by passing it as an argument. And I still recommend you check the order in which the two functions get called; the order should not be coupled.

Answer (score 0):

Layout for tabs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#ffffff">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            android:background="#000000"
            app:titleTextColor="#ffffff"

            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/PopupMenuStyle">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:id="@+id/textview"
                android:textColor="@color/colorTrueWhite"/>

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <!-- our tablayout to display tabs  -->
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorBlack"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"

            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorTrueWhite"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="5dp"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

        <!-- View pager to swipe views -->


        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>


    </LinearLayout>
```

Activity using that layout:

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener {

    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    public static ViewPager viewPager;
    public static Context ctx;
    Pager adapter;
    public static int expired, paid;
    Boolean isConnection;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        Toolbar tb = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(tb);

        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);

        //getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


        ctx = getApplicationContext();


        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);


        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);


        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("title1"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("title2"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("title3"));
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        adapter = new Pager(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount(), ctx);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);


        if(some condition)
        {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
        }
        else
        {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
        }
        viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);

        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(this);

        ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) tabLayout.getChildAt(0);
        int tabsCount = vg.getChildCount();
        for (int j = 0; j < tabsCount; j++) {
            ViewGroup vgTab = (ViewGroup) vg.getChildAt(j);
            int tabChildsCount = vgTab.getChildCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < tabChildsCount; i++) {
                View tabViewChild = vgTab.getChildAt(i);
                if (tabViewChild instanceof TextView) {
                    ((TextView) tabViewChild).setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD);
                }
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
    }


}
```

Pager code:

```
public class Pager extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter
{
    int tabcount;
    Context ctx;
    private String [] Titles = {"title1", "title2", "title3"};

    public Pager(FragmentManager fm, int tabcount, Context ctx)
    {
        super(fm);
        this.tabcount = tabcount;
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return tabcount;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return Titles[position];
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {

            case 0:
                Tab1 tab1 = new Tab1();
                return tab1;

            case 1:
                Tab2 tab2 = new Tab2();
                return tab2;

            case 2:
                Tab3 tab3 = new Tab3();
                return tab3;

            default:
                return null;
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

solved this problem by using **Framgnet Callbacks** as described in here http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html I believe that this is the best was to pass fragment TextViews into my activity after they are created.

Answer (score 0):

The `onCreateView()` method is called after `fragmentTransaction.commit()`.
Since, you are calling `setTitle()` before `fragmentTransaction.commit()`, the TextView instance `title` is not instantiated and so is null.
Add the line `fragment.setTitle()` after `fragmentTransaction.commit()`.